# How to use HttpClient to consume the data from an xml content site and return them as List of Json object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

Here, I have a sample link which contains xml data as shown below. As you can see on the xml content from the given link,
there are xml element `<DisplayName>Name of the employee</DisplayName>`.I want to get all the values from the ***DisplayName*** elements. How to get the content of every xml element ***DisplayName*** and return them as
***list of json objects***? So far, here's what I have tried below but it doesn't return anything. When I put a breakpoint, I found out that the ***response.IsSuccessStatusCode = false***
and the ***ReasonPhrase*** and **StatusCode** is ***Unauthorized***. How do I get this thing done and what I've been missing?

```
 private const string URL = "https://apidev.mysite.net/employees/";
        [Route("api/Personnel/UserNames")]
        [HttpGet]
       public List<ADGroup> AutocompleteUserNames(string searchText)
        {

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

            // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // List data response.
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(searchText).Result;
            //  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                List<ADGroup> result = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<ADGroup>>(data);            
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                 return new List<ADGroup>();

            }
        }
```

Sample link:
***https://apidev.mysite.net/employees/shea***

XML content of the link:

```
<ArrayOfEmployeeVm xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MySite.Api.WebApi.Models">
<EmployeeVm>
<ActiveDirectoryName>dfhdfhdffhf</ActiveDirectoryName>
<BusinessPhone>4646456</BusinessPhone>
<DisplayName>Shea, Danny J.</DisplayName>
<Email>timothy.shea@mysite.com</Email>
<EmployeeId>19072</EmployeeId>
<EmployeeIdOriginal>19072</EmployeeIdOriginal>
<FirstName>Danny J.</FirstName>
<FullName>Danny J. Shea</FullName>
<IsActive>true</IsActive>
<LastName>Shea</LastName>
<Office>Boston</Office>
<PracticeGroup>HLB Consulting</PracticeGroup>
<Title>Of Counsel</Title>
</EmployeeVm>

<EmployeeVm>
<ActiveDirectoryName>MPtshdfh</ActiveDirectoryName>
<BusinessPhone>+4546556</BusinessPhone>
<DisplayName>Shearer, Dennis D.</DisplayName>
<Email>dennis.shearer@mysite.com</Email>
<EmployeeId>60048</EmployeeId>
<EmployeeIdOriginal>60048</EmployeeIdOriginal>
<FirstName>Dennis D.</FirstName>
<FullName>Dennis D. Shearer</FullName>
<IsActive>true</IsActive>
<LastName>Shearer</LastName>
<Office>San Francisco</Office>
<PracticeGroup>Office Services</PracticeGroup>
<Title>Facilities Manager</Title>
</EmployeeVm>

<EmployeeVm>
<ActiveDirectoryName>MPghdjgj</ActiveDirectoryName>
<BusinessPhone>+45645757</BusinessPhone>
<DisplayName>Shea, Ted P.</DisplayName>
<Email>ted.shea@mysite.com</Email>
<EmployeeId>74251</EmployeeId>
<EmployeeIdOriginal>74251</EmployeeIdOriginal>
<FirstName>Ted P.</FirstName>
<FullName>Ted P. Shea</FullName>
<IsActive>true</IsActive>
<LastName>Shea</LastName>
<Office>Philadelphia</Office>
<PracticeGroup>Information Technology</PracticeGroup>
<Title>Chief Information Officer</Title>
</EmployeeVm>
</ArrayOfEmployeeVm>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remote service is returning response as **"Unauthorized"**. So, before retrieving data from service, you should perform **Authorization**  and it depends on of remote service's authorization type. It might be Windows Authentication, Basic Authentication or something like that.

If the remote service is configured as **Windows Authentication**, you can try to set credentials for `HttpClient`;

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Comment: That is my problem right now if how I could determine the type of authorization to use and if indeed be Windows Authentication. How would I perform it? Do you have any sample of that?